# Передача данных MessagePack

Tags: javascript, python, django

Пытаюсь передавать с бэка Python Django данные в формате [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/).
Из модели я получаю данные, которые пытаюсь упаковать в MessagePack, однако если попытаться упаковывать сразу объекты(при получении из модели, они поставляются в формате QuerySet), то стандартный msgpack.packb - не сработает, т.к. не умеет с этим типом взаимодействовать. Поэтому я использую библиотеку nameko-django(возможно, кто-то еще знает возможные решения, но суть не в этом). Получаем в представлении(views.py) такую функцию:

```
qs = list(Post.objects.filter(published=True))
data = dumps(qs)
return HttpResponse(data)
```

Благодаря "**list**(Post.objects...)" серелизуется не только название объекта, но и все возможные поля(как раз то, что и нужно). В итоге получаем данные, как на скриншоте(неизвестные символы отображаются из-за того, что браузер не понимает двоичного формата).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы получить данные со страницы API и отобразить у клиента используется VANILA JS:

```js
 function loadContentPost() {
    
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // Проверим, пришел ли запрос - 200 запрос прошел. === - проверка и по значению и по типу. Они должны быть равны
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            // Получаем данные из запроса
            console.log(this.responseText)


                   **    //преобразование в байты для MessagePack
            var bytes = []; // char codes

            for (var i = 0; i < this.responseText.length; ++i) {
            var code = this.responseText.charCodeAt(i);

            bytes = bytes.concat([code]);
            }
            // for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            //  output.value += input[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + " ";
            // }
            const content = msgpack.deserialize(bytes);
            console.log(bytes)
**



            let html = "";
            console.log(content)
            for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
                const fields = content[i].fields;
                
                let date = new Date(fields.time_create_post.slice(0, fields.time_create_post.indexOf('.')));
                
                date = `${date.getDate()}.${date.getMonth()+1 > 10 ? date.getMonth()+1 : '0'.concat(date.getMonth()+1)}.${date.getFullYear()} ${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}`;
                
                html += `<a href="./post/${content[i].pk}-${fields.slug}">
                <li>
                    <div class="post">
                        <div class="img__post">\n`;

                if (fields.image !== "") {
                    html += `<img class="image__post" src="/media/${fields.image}">\n`;
                }
                html += `</div>
                        <div class="text__post">
                            <div class="content__post">
                            <h1 class="headPostTitle">${fields.title}</h1>
                            <p class="dataPost">${date}</p>                   
                            <p class="headPostContent">${fields.content.replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, "").split(' ').filter( str => str != '').slice(0, 65).join(' ')} ...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
            </a>`;
            }
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = html;
        }
    };
    
    http.open("GET", `./api/msgpack/` , true); // тут исправить на
    nextItem += count;
    http.send();
    
}
loadContentPost();
```

Следующими строками из вышеуказанного кода, я получаю закодированный текст, со страницы API, после чего преобразовываю его в байты(числа), для того, чтобы ДЕсерелизатор понимал что это MessagePack:

```js
var bytes = []; // char codes

            for (var i = 0; i < this.responseText.length; ++i) {
            var code = this.responseText.charCodeAt(i);

            bytes = bytes.concat([code]);
            }
            // for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            //  output.value += input[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + " ";
            // }
            const content = msgpack.deserialize(bytes);
            console.log(bytes)
            let html = "";
            console.log(content)
```

Единственный (де)серелизатор на MessagePack для JS сайтов я нашел от [ygoe](https://github.com/ygoe/msgpack.js).
Однако, после десерелизациия, получаю значение "-3", а не текст, который мне нужен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как возможно, распаковать на фронте данные зашифрованные в MessagePack?**

p.s. во views.py можно еще сделать передачу через msgpack.packb, однако для это нужно изначально серелизовать в JSON и только потом в messagepack, я понимаю, что это не правильно, но как вариант - имеет право на существование. Однако та же проблема , с получение данных на фронте.